# Determine value of cell in Excel from Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using Outlook VBA to find if a cell is empty on an Excel sheet.

The code will write content from email in the cells but fails to register any values in the cell.

After the normal Outlook VBA setup with MAPI etc., the code is:

```
Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
Dim xlwb As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim x, y As Long          
Dim Iscellempty As Boolean
Dim Budapest As Range
Iscellempty = False
```

This opens the file but will not reopen if open already

```
Set xlapp = GetObject(, "excel.application")
On Error Resume Next        
Set xlwb = xlapp.Workbooks("Excel test.xlsm")    
If xlwb Is Nothing Then      
    xlapp.Workbooks.Open ("U:\Workarea\Automation Tool\AmendCancel report\Excel test.xlsm")      
    Set xlwb = xlapp.Workbooks("Excel test.xlsm")
   Else   
End If

Set xlws = xlwb.Sheets(1)    
If xlwb Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Required file is not available"
End If

x = 2
y = CLng(Date) - 43105
```

This next part is the issue. When hovering the cursor over 'Budapest' it will always say 'Nothing' (and it fails to say anything at all when adding .value

```
Set Budapest = xlws.Cells(y, 3)
Do
With xlwb.Worksheets(1) etc....
```

The If statement following this fails to trigger giving the same output regardless of the cell being empty or not.

Comment: Your y calculation looks odd...can u explain

Comment: Comment out the `On Error Resume Next` and see where the real errors are

Comment: Ctznkane25- The y variable gives a new row on each day an email is sent. There is probably an easier way to do it. It the case above it is 5, tomorrow it will be 6.

Comment: Tim Williams- Good idea, I will try that 1st thing tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

*To simply check if cell value is empty from Outlook, you can use [**IsEmpty Function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/isempty-function)*

```
Set rCell = Sht.Range("A1")
If Not IsEmpty(rCell.value) Then
    Debug.Print rCell.value
End If
```

*Or another Example to Avoid Empty Spaces*

```
Set rCell = Sht.Range("A1")
If Not Len(Trim(rCell.value)) = 0 Then
    Debug.Print rCell.value
End If
```

*Here is full Example from Outlook that will open Excel file or reopen Excel file*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim Book As Excel.Workbook
    Dim Sht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlStarted As Boolean
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim rCell As Range

'   // File Path
    FilePath = "C:\Temp\Book1.xlsm"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
            xlStarted = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

'   // Open Workbook, Sheet1 to get data
    Set Book = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    Set Sht = Book.Sheets("Sheet1")

'   // Set range variable
    Set rCell = Sht.Range("A1")
    If Not Len(Trim(rCell.value)) = 0 Then
        Debug.Print rCell.value ' Immediate Window
    End If

    Set rCell = Sht.Range("A1")
    If Not IsEmpty(rCell.value) Then
        Debug.Print rCell.value ' Immediate Window
    End If

'   // Close & SaveChanges
    Book.Close SaveChanges:=True
    If xlStarted Then
        xlApp.Quit
    End If

    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: @ElliottJamesBurton if this was helpful please mark the answer- thanks